# Use diamond operator in a libgdx project

Tags: java, android, libgdx, java-7

I am trying to use the diamond error in a libgdx project which I have imported into Android Studio. However, I get the following error message:

> Error:(34, 50) Gradle: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
>   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

How do I configure my project to use `-source 7` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some google-foo finally found the answer in [#libgdx chat transcripts](http://echelog.com/logs/browse/libgdx/1417906800). I found every occurrence of `sourceCompatibility` in the existing `build.gradle` files (using Ctrl-Shift-F or Edit->Find->Find in Path...) and changing the value from `'1.6'` to `'1.7'`.